# converting between const wchar_t* and const char* and the reverse using macros

Tags: c++, string, winapi, macros

I'm trying to make my win32 program interchangeable between character sets (Unicode and Multi-Byte) the macros such as CreateWindowEx() use wchar_t* and char* depending on the set and for my class name I have it stored in a variable in a windowClass Class.

```
static constexpr const wchar_t* wndClassName = L"windowclass";
```

at the moment for other functions I've been using macros I have created defined in a header file

```
#pragma once
#include <sstream>

#ifdef _UNICODE

#define ConstString(constStringIn) (std::wstringstream() << constStringIn).str().c_str() //used as arguments in functions
#define STRINGALIASMACRO wchar_t* //Used as function return tpyes and wndClassName

#endif // _UNICODE

#ifdef _MBCS

#define ConstString(constStringIn) (std::stringstream() << constStringIn).str().c_str()
#define STRINGALIASMACRO char*

#endif // _MBCS
```

when trying to replace the `wchar_t*` with `STRINGALIASMACRO` and `ConstString("windowclass")` for the wndClassName variable value the error `expression must have a constant value`

What could I do to fix this and is it good practice to use macros as type definitions and return types instead of e.g `typedef wchar_t* STRINGALIAS` I did try this and I got a whole bunch of other errors.

Comment: The `_T()` macro defined in `tchar.h` does all of this already.  If you're curious how it works, look how it's implemented.

Comment: Unless you are specifically targeting Windows 95, there's no reason call the ANSI version of any API. Just use the Unicode version everywhere. Libraries are more useful if they don't provide meaningless options (such as using ANSI character encoding).

Comment: As for the specific error: A `constexpr` variable must be initialized with an expression that is a constant value. Clearly, piping into `std::wstringstream()` isn't going to be very `constexpr`, so there's that. This is not to say that you couldn't implement a `constexpr` UTF-16 encoder. You can, no problem. The thing you cannot make `constexpr` is evaluating the current code page that's only available at run time.

Comment: As of Windows 10 (1903 - May 2019 update), the -A function variants are UTF-8 savvy, if ANSI code page is configured for UTF-8.  q.v. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page#-a-vs--w-apis).  Also, since Windows 10 build 17134 (April 2018 update), the Universal C Runtime supports using a [UTF-8 code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).  (Thanks to @phuclv for the tip.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie technically, the `_T()` macro is for the C runtime library. The Win32 equivalent is the `TEXT()` macro. The `_UNICODE` (C) and `UNICODE` (Win32) conditionals are typically (un)set together, so the macros are usually interchangeable, but they are technically from separate APIs and should not be mixed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, forgot to mention `TEXT()` also.

Comment: @elj Yes, indeed. But you will have to provide a manifest with your binary to opt-in. That's not something you get to control at compile time, when implementing a library. And even if you did, why incur a run time cost to convert a string from UTF-8 to UTF-16, when the compiler can do that for you? We're talking about a `constexpr` variable here after all.

Comment: Time traveller from the late 20th century

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 API (and the C runtime library) already provide their own sets of preprocessor macros for this exact purpose.  Look at:

`TCHAR`/`_TCHAR` = `char` or `wchar_t`
`LP(C)TSTR` = `(const) char*` or `(const) wchar_t*`
`TEXT("literal")`/`_T("literal")` = `"literal"` or `L"literal"`
`TEXT('literal')`/`_T('literal')` = `'literal'` or `L'literal'`

For example:

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>

#define ConstString(constStringIn) TEXT(constStringIn) //used as arguments in functions
typedef LPTSTR STRINGALIASMACRO; //Used as function return tpyes and wndClassName
typedef LPCTSTR CONSTSTRINGALIASMACRO; //Used as function return tpyes and wndClassName
```

```
static constexpr CONSTSTRINGALIASMACRO wndClassName = ConstString("windowclass");
```

Or simply:

```
static constexpr LPCTSTR wndClassName = TEXT("windowclass");
```

See the following for more details:

[Win32 Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

[Working With Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings)

[Generic-Text Mappings in tchar.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/generic-text-mappings-in-tchar-h)

[What are TCHAR, WCHAR, LPSTR, LPWSTR, LPCTSTR (etc.)?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc)